# How to configure ssl with node

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, angular-universal, server-side-rendering

I'm new Angular and Node Stuff.
I'm trying to run my angular application on node along with https/ssl.
I have installed following files using certbot

```
git clone https://github.com/certbot/certbot 

cert.pem -> ../../archive/mypleaks.com/cert1.pem
chain.pem -> ../../archive/mypleaks.com/chain1.pem
fullchain.pem -> ../../archive/mypleaks.com/fullchain1.pem
privkey.pem -> ../../archive/mypleaks.com/privkey1.pem
```

Then I converted cert.pem to key.pem and server.cert using below commands in ssl folder inside application.

```
sudo openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -new -nodes -keyout /etc/letsencrypt/live/mypleaks.com/cert.pem -out key.pem
sudo openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in key.pem -signkey /etc/letsencrypt/live/mypleaks.com/cert.pem -out server.crt
```

Then I followed this [article link](https://medium.com/@mafshin/enable-angular-universal-for-existing-app-3a17694b9177) and configured prod.js

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 443;
const server = require('./dist/server');
var fs = require('fs'), 
https = require('https');
var options  = { 
key: fs.readFileSync('./ssl/key.pem'),
cert: fs.readFileSync('./ssl/server.crt')
};
var httpsServer = https.createServer(options, server.app).listen(port, () => {
console.log("Express server listening on port " + port);
});
```

After building project using `npm run build:prod`, when I'm running `npm run prod` it's below throwing error:-

```
> myPleaks@0.0.0 prod /Users/deraj/home/mypleaks-ui/myPleaks
> node prod.js

Using browser-only version of superagent in non-browser environment
_tls_common.js:104
      c.context.setKey(options.key, options.passphrase);
                ^

Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line
    at Object.createSecureContext (_tls_common.js:104:17)
    at Server (_tls_wrap.js:805:25)
    at new Server (https.js:54:14)
    at Object.createServer (https.js:76:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/deraj/home/mypleaks-ui/myPleaks/prod.js:10:25)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! myPleaks@0.0.0 prod: `node prod.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the myPleaks@0.0.0 prod script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/deraj/.npm/_logs/2018-10-07T19_49_16_195Z-debug.log
```

I tried Hard but couldn't fix the error. Please suggest me some solution.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your pem files are invalid.

I never created that way, some time ago i was doing exactly what are you doing and I created that pem files following this:

https://certbot.eff.org/

You just need to choose your "software" and "system" and follow the tutorial.

Comment: I tried this one as well keeping server none and OS ubuntu, but its giving me only cert.pem, privateKey.pem and chain.pem where as I need two files key.pem and server.cert. So I need to convert but when I'm converting these files it's not working. At first place I'm confused which file should be used from cert.pem, privateKey.pem and chain.pem to generate key.pem and server.cert. Second why it's throwing this error.?

Comment: As i said, probably your files are incorrect. They should look like that:
key.pem
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
a lot of characters
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----

server.cert
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
a lot of characters
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

Comment: And you dont need to convert anything, just use fullchain.pem as certificate (you are calling that as server.cert) and privkey.pem as private key (you are calling that as privateKey.pem)